# Pine script error Mismatched input 'entryShort' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am getting the following error:

> Mismatched input 'entryShort' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

I can't figure out why this error is occurring:

[Screenshot showing the error in the compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTYXc.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("EMA Bounce Entry", overlay=true)

// Define EMA length
emaLen = 100

// Calculate the 100 EMA
ema = ema(close, emaLen)

// Identify closing price above/below EMA for potential entry
aboveEMA = close > ema
elowEMA = close < ema

// Entry condition: Price bounces off EMA (closes above after being below or vice versa)
entryLong = if belowEMA[1] and aboveEMA
entryShort = if aboveEMA[1] and belowEMA // Fix: Remove extra indentation

// Plot the EMA
plot(ema, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="100 EMA")

// Mark potential entry points with triangles (optional)
if entryLong
  triangle(up=true, color=color.green, size=size.tiny, location=close)
if entryShort
  triangle(down=true, color=color.red, size=size.tiny, location=close)

// Generate entry orders (modify as needed)
// This example uses alerts for illustration, replace with your order logic
if entryLong
  alert("Long Entry", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, alert.success)
if entryShort
  alert("Short Entry", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, alert.failure)
```

The code should compile.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using an unnecessary if statement in the code:

Just this should suffice:

```
entryLong = belowEMA[1] and aboveEMA
entryShort = aboveEMA[1] and belowEMA
```

For this exact code, the following will also do:

```
entryLong = ta.crossover(close, ema)
entryShort = ta.crossunder(close, ema)
```

Also, is `triangle()` a function that you have created using `plotshape()`? I am asking because it is not visible in your code. Otherwise, that line of code will also give an error. Below is the proper syntax for a triangle up:

```
plotshape(entryLong, "Up", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.green, size = size.tiny)
```